# When does a limit reach a value $< 1$?

Tags: number-theory, infinite-product

I'm working on a proof in number theory, and have encountered a proof. If I include the proof, I can show that as some numbers tends to infinity, they follow a certain rule. Unfortunately, this is not precise enough, so I have set  up an inequality. This is the limit:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} g \cdot \left(1-(1-\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{p_i}))\right)$$

and know that it tends to $0$. In this case, $p_i$ are the prime numbers, and $g$ is any number in-between $p_{n}+1 $ and $p_{n+1} -1$. I would like to know at which n the expression is less than $1$. In other words/symbols:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} g \cdot \left(1-(1-\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{p_i}))\right) < 1.$$
I've written [a short bit of code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150442/large-number-limit-extravaganza) in Python and had it reviewed on Code Review. Since I've tried numbers up to 100 million and did not reach a number less than $1$, I would like to know whether there is some mathematical of  arriving at the result, or whether my limit is just wrong. Thanks!

Comment: And $p_i$ is prime numbers?

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes, thanks for recommending the clarification.

Comment: Note that $1 - (1 - \prod) = \prod$. Also, by [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems), the limit is $+\infty$, the product is asymptotically $e^{-\gamma}/\log p_n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand your simplification but disagree with your limit. I think that the product converges to 0 thus the limit becomes 0.

Comment: Well, Mertens proved that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\log x)\prod_{p \leqslant x}\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p}\biggr) = e^{-\gamma}.$$ And $\dfrac{n}{\log p_n} \to +\infty$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer But his product looks like it is for "the first n prime numbers", not for "the prime numbers less than n".

Comment: @Momo "The first $n$ prime numbers" are "the primes not exceeding the $n$-th prime number". Hence we have the product $\prod\limits_{p \leqslant p_n} \bigl(1 - \frac{1}{p}\bigr)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer It was made clear to me in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044965/sum-of-an-infinite-series-of-fractions) post that 1 - the product converges to 1.

Comment: @LinusRastegar if you use that argument only to conclude that this limit is 0, then you might be in trouble because this is in fact a $\infty \cdot 0$ scenario, which may be anything ...

Comment: @LinusRastegar It does. And Mertens' third theorem says how fast. You get a finite nonzero limit if $g \sim \log p_n$.

Comment: I think I'll just be posting a new question with the limit as the question and not the inequality. Thanks for doubting my work (not trying to be passive aggressive, I really appreciate it) and making me think more!

Comment: Why the $(1-(1-P))$?  Why not just $P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A counter proof** ... I feel like stealing the answer from Daniel Fischer, but [here is evidence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726488/finding-an-upperbound-for-sum-i-2n-bigg-prod-k-2i-dfracp-k-2p-k/) I knew about [Mertens' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) before. To avoid any further doubts:

$$ g \cdot \left(1-\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\right)\right) \geq (p_{n}+1)\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{p_{n}+1}{\ln{(p_n+1)}}\cdot \ln{(p_n+1)} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{p_{n}+1}{\ln{(p_n+1)}}\cdot e^{-\gamma} \cdot \frac{\ln{(p_n+1)} \cdot \prod_{i < p_n+1} \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)}{e^{-\gamma}}>$$
$$>\frac{p_{n}+1}{\ln{(p_n+1)}}\cdot e^{-\gamma} \cdot (1-\varepsilon)$$
starting with some $n$ for some $\varepsilon$ (from the definition of limit). The latter goes to $\infty$.

**Another way** (to add some creativity from me) is to exploit [this result](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html):
$$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \varphi(n)\cdot \frac{\ln{\ln{n}}}{n}=e^{-\gamma}$$
where $$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)=\frac{\varphi\left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i\right)}{\prod_{i=1}^n p_i}$$ 
so that
$$g \cdot \left(1-\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\right)\right) \geq (p_{n}+1)\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)=(p_{n}+1)\cdot \frac{\varphi\left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i\right)}{\prod_{i=1}^n p_i}=$$
$$=\frac{p_{n}+1}{\ln{\ln{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i\right)}}}\cdot \varphi\left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i\right) \cdot \frac{\ln{\ln{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i\right)}}}{\prod_{i=1}^n p_i}>$$
considering the definition of $\liminf$
$$>\frac{p_{n}+1}{\ln{\ln{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i\right)}}} \cdot (1-\varepsilon) \cdot e^{-\gamma}=$$
(from some $n$ onwards of course)
$$=\frac{p_{n}+1}{\ln{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \ln{p_i}\right)}} \cdot (1-\varepsilon) \cdot e^{-\gamma} > \frac{p_{n}+1}{\ln{\left(n\cdot \ln{p_n}\right)}} \cdot (1-\varepsilon) \cdot e^{-\gamma}=\frac{p_{n}+1}{\ln{n} + \ln{\ln{p_n}}} \cdot (1-\varepsilon) \cdot e^{-\gamma}$$
which again [is easy to see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) it goes to $\infty$.